# Should this pipe have condensation inside of it?

Tags: condensation

Just wondering if it’s normal for some condensation buildup inside this pipe on my HVAC unit. It doesn’t appear at this time that there is enough condensation to drip down onto the electrical components below it. But my concern is if it does end up getting to that point? Is this normal?it’s gotten real hot and humid the last few days here in the Midwest. I assume that has some relation to it. But wondering if this is an issue I need to have addressed asap… thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: Is your condensation drip drain still working (to the outside) or is it clogged

Comment: I’m not sure that I have a drip drain to the outside of my home. But in my furnace room where the HVAC is located there’s a condensation drip line/pipe that’s drips right into a drain in the same room at the bottom of the unit. That appears to be working just fine, I can see water slowly dripping out of it.

Comment: Also is the pipe in question on my picture, is that considered the flue vent pipe?? I haven’t found anything online that is telling me for sure what that pipe is..

Comment: What model is it ?

Comment: I have a Carrier system. I believe it’s a high efficiency system. Don’t know the exact model off hand. But it’s newer-ish, my house was built in 2017.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fresh air intake that brings in outdoor air for combustion when your furnace makes heat. If the house is sealed tight, anything that blows inside air out of the house (clothes dryer, bathroom vent, range hood) will cause outdoor air to enter the house through that circled pipe.

Outdoor air is currently hot and humid and the pipe is indoors and cool, so moisture will condense in the pipe and drip into your furnace. If you are sure the drips are doing no harm, forget about it. I would be concerned that constant drips might cause rust inside your furnace.

If you are feeling adventurous, you might mount a funnel under the dripping pipe without blocking air flow and route a plastic tube from the funnel to your condensate drain.

If this were my house, I would turn off the gas supply to the furnace for the summer, place a hang tag on the gas valve that says REMOVE OUTSIDE FRESH AIR CAP BEFORE OPERATING and then I would cap the PVC pipe outside with a PCV pipe cap using no glue. That will stop the moist air from entering the house through that pipe. Remove the cap before you turn the gas back on in the fall.